# Issue displaying website on mobile phone that is using angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

The angular app is not displaying correctly on mobile.
The app displays correctly on the website.

here is the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-HFvBv9sDk

as you can see, the app displays perfectly when you adjust the size of the screen using Chrome.

For some reason, the menu is not displaying correctly when viewing the website through mobile.

any ideas what might be causing this

this is the code for the header:
HTML:::

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!sidenav.opened"> menu </mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="sidenav.opened"> close </mat-icon>
  </button>
  <p [@titleState]="showTitle">Lead Axis</p>
</mat-toolbar>



<mat-sidenav-container>

  <mat-sidenav #sidenav="matSidenav" (click)="onHideSideNav()">
    <img class="avatar mat-elevation-z8 rotate-image"
      src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/52751567413_2576076f94.jpg" />

    <h4 class="name">Lead Axis</h4>
    <p class="designation">Worlds premier leads platform</p>

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>

    <button *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated" mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/channelData">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">analytics</mat-icon>
      <span>Purchased data</span>
    </button>


    <button *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated" mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/settings">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position" >settings</mat-icon>
      <span>Settings</span>
    </button>

    <button *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated" mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/transactions">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">receipt_long</mat-icon>
      <span>Transactions</span>
    </button>


    <button *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated" mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/myBuyingCampaigns">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">work_history</mat-icon>
      <span>My campaign</span>
    </button>

    <button *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated" mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/createBuyingCampaign">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">campaign</mat-icon>
      <span>Create campaign</span>
    </button>


    <button *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated" mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/createChannel">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">storefront</mat-icon>
      <span>Create channel</span>
    </button>

    <button *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated" mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/listChannel">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">corporate_fare</mat-icon>
      <span>My channels</span>
    </button>

    <button *ngIf="!userIsAuthenticated" mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/auth/signup">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">person_add</mat-icon>
      <span>Signup</span>
    </button>

    <button *ngIf="!userIsAuthenticated" mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/auth/login">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">login</mat-icon>
      <span>Login</span>
    </button>

    <button *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated" (click)="onLogout()" mat-button class="menu-button">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">Logout</mat-icon>
      <span>Logout</span>
    </button>

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>

    <button mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/developer">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">code</mat-icon>
      <span>Developer</span>
    </button>

    <button mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/terms-and-conditions">
      <mat-icon [@photoState]="position">policy</mat-icon>
      <span>Terms</span>
    </button>

  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="content mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

here is the code for the ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { MatSidenav } from "@angular/material";
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { AuthService } from "../shared-services/auth.service";
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';
@Component({
  selector: "app-header",
  templateUrl: "./header.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./header.component.scss"],
  animations: [
    trigger('titleState', [
      state('show', style({
        opacity: 1
      })),
      state('hide', style({
        opacity: 0
      })),
      transition('show=>hide', animate('600ms ease-out')),
      transition('hide=>show', animate('600ms ease-out'))

    ]),
    trigger('photoState', [
      state('enlarge', style({ transform: 'scale(1.5)', })),
      transition('small <=> enlarge', animate('2s ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ]

})



export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  userIsAuthenticated = false;
  private authListenerSubs: Subscription;

  @ViewChild(MatSidenav, { static: true }) sidenav!: MatSidenav;
  isTitleShown = false;
  position='enlarge';

  get showTitle() {
    return this.isTitleShown ? 'show' : 'hide';
  }

  toggleShowTitle() {
    
    this.isTitleShown =  !this.isTitleShown;
  }

  togglePosition(){
    this.position = 'small';
  }




  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private observer: BreakpointObserver
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.observer.observe(['(max-width:800px']).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.matches) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.sidenav.mode = 'over';
          this.sidenav.close();
        });
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.sidenav.mode = 'side';
          this.sidenav.open();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  setAuthentication() {
    this.userIsAuthenticated = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    this.authListenerSubs = this.authService
      .getAuthStatusListener()
      .subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
        this.userIsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
      });
  }

  setAnimationTimer(){

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.toggleShowTitle();
      this.togglePosition();
    }, 1000)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setAuthentication();
    this.setAnimationTimer();


    
  }

  onHideSideNav() {
    console.log("this.sidenav", this.sidenav)
    if (this.sidenav.mode === 'over') {
      this.sidenav.toggle()
    }
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.authListenerSubs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```